# Issue keyboard input to a particular window without interrupting background in Windows

Tags: c#, python, input

I need to be able to issue keyboard input to a particular window in the background on a periodic basis without interrupting the user.  How could this be done?

**Use case:**

I have two windows open: one window is waiting for the input (window A), and I'm actively working in another window (window B).  While working in window B, periodic commands are issued to window A through the keyboard without interrupting the interactivity going on in window B.

I'm hoping to accomplish this using Python or C#...whichever gets the job done cleanest and fastest (or a nice hybrid thereof).

Comment: I'm assuming you're on Windows since you want to use C#. If so, this is probably not very easy. The typical way to accomplish keyboard input is SendKeys in .NET, but that requires an active window. You might look into DDE, but that can get a little messy depending on the application you want to use it with.

Answer (score 0):

Check [winGuiAuto.py](http://www.brunningonline.net/simon/blog/archives/winGuiAuto.py.html). If you can find the hwnd for the control whose input you want to change, you can send it to it even if it's not the active window.

Even it doesn't solve your problem directly, the source code is a good lesson on using the win32api with Python and should help you anyway.

Comment: Do you know if this will work in a command prompt window?  The window I'd be sending input to would actually be a command prompt.  There isn't any "form" to speak of...

Comment: No, it certainly won't work with a command prompt. With this you would be effectively changing the content of the entry you want to send input to. I believe the only possible approach with a command prompt is the SendKeys @root45 mentioned, but that only works for the active window.